# Window of JWindow doesn't move

Tags: java, swing, jwindow

I have a frame extends from `JWindow` (because I want to handle my X and - buttons) so I don't want it decorated. My problem is when I run the application I can't drag my window - it's fixed in a certain location. My code is as follows (the class i big so i picked the related section):

public class StatisticsMainFrame extends JWindow{

```
public StatisticsMainFrame()
{
     bodyPane = new JPanel();
    bodyPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bodyPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    sideBannerPane = new JPanel(); // program banner
    buttonsPane = new JPanel(); // contains buttons
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));
    contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500)); 
    // contentPane contains some panel for display data


    Container container = new Container();
    container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    container.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
    container.add(sideBannerPane);
    container.add(buttonsPane);
    container.add(contentPane);

    Container cont = new Container();
    cont.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cont, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    //cont.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    //cont.add(custDecorationPane);
    cont.add(container);
    add(cont);
    // Adding Panes

    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    //setUndecorated(true);
    pack();

}

public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    new StatisticsMainFrame().setVisible(true);
}


private CustomFrameDecorationButtons custDecorationPane;
private JPanel bodyPane;
private JPanel contentPane;
private JPanel sideBannerPane;
private JPanel buttonsPane;

// buttonsPane components
private JLabel general_lbl;
private JLabel Diagnosis_lbl;
private JLabel chemotherapy_lbl;
private JLabel radiotherapy_lbl;
private JLabel surgery_lbl;
private JLabel hermonalTherapy_lbl;

private RootButton generalStatistics_btn;
private RootButton statOfAffectedSys_btn;
private RootButton statOfGrade_btn;
private RootButton statOfCombinations_btn;
private RootButton statOfResponses_btn;
private RootButton statOfRadiotherapy_btn;
private RootButton statOfSurgery_btn;
private RootButton statOfHermonaltherapy_btn;

private GeneralStatisticsContentPanel generalStatPane;
private StatisticsOfAffectedSystemPanel2 statOfAffectedSysPanel2;
private StatisticsOfGradePanel statOFGradingPanel;
private ChemotherapyCombinationStatisticsPanel statChemotherapyCombinationPanel;
private ChemotherapyResponseStatisticsPanel statChemotherapyResponsePanel;
private RadiotherapyStatisticsPanel radiotherapyPanel;
private SurgeryStatisticsPanel surgeryStatPanel;
private HermonaltherapyStatisticsPanel hermonaltherapy;
```

}

Comment: I can't see a `JWindow` in your code. Do you mind posting a [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html)?

Comment: thnx asif... actually i do this things but sometimes i got unsuitable answers.. but anyway thnx..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a custom drag using for example the following code:

```
addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
    private int mx, my;

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        mx = e.getXOnScreen();
        my = e.getYOnScreen();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        Point p = StatisticsMainFrame.this.getLocation();
        p.x += e.getXOnScreen() - mx;
        p.y += e.getYOnScreen() - my;
        mx = e.getXOnScreen();
        my = e.getYOnScreen();
        StatisticsMainFrame.this.setLocation(p);
    }
});
```

If you place this snippet directly in the constructor of `StatisticsMainFrame` you can use the mouse to drag the window by clicking anywhere inside the window. (You can also add the listener to any other component.)